# Maven Multi-Module-Project works in IntelliJ but running via command line says "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I started writing a basic Hello World Multi-Module project with Maven inside IntelliJ. It runs perfectly with the built-in run button, but when I build the project via command line with `mvn install` and then try running it with `java -cp HelloWorld/target/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar App`, it says

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> MoreDataClass     at App.main(App.java:5) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MoreDataClass   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Maybe the problem is the project structure (which was given to my by IntelliJ):

```
parent/
– pom.xml
– HelloWorld/
– – pom.xml
– – src/main/java/App.java
– GetMoreData/
– – pom.xml
– – src/main/java/MoreDataClass.java
```

The `App.java` inside the `HelloWorld`-Module looks like this:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        MoreDataClass c = new MoreDataClass();
        System.out.println(c.getMoreData());
    }
}
```

And the `MoreDataClass` inside `GetMoreData`-Module contains this code:

```
public class MoreDataClass {
    public String getMoreData() {
        return "Here is some more data from the Module GetMoreData";
    }
}
```

Running `App.main()` in IntelliJ returns (as supposed to) the following lines at standard out:

```
Hello World
Here is some more data from the Module GetMoreData
```

Running it via Maven in the command line (as described at the beginning) on the other hand returns this:

```
Hello World
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MoreDataClass
    at App.main(App.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MoreDataClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

So the `App.main()` is built and can be executed, but it doesn't find the `MoreDataClass`. Why doesn't it?

In case those are relevant to the problem, here are my pom.xml:

```
****** parent/pom.xml: ******

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.playground.multiModule</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>GetMoreData</module>
        <module>HelloWord</module>
    </modules>

</project>

***** parent/GetMoreData/pom.xml *****

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>de.playground.multiModule</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>GetMoreData</artifactId>

</project>

***** parent/HelloWorld/pom.xml *****

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>de.playground.multiModule</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>HelloWord</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.playground.multiModule</groupId>
            <artifactId>GetMoreData</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `GetMoreData` jar to classpath, or configure the `HelloWorld`s build to generate [jar-with-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)